# Django Rest Framework + Swagger UI

Tags: django-rest-framework, swagger-ui

I have an API I am working on, I have a serializer as below:

```
class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserRefSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        exclude = ('id',)
        extra_kwargs = {
            'public_id': {'read_only': True},
            'user': {'read_only': True},
            'created_at': {'read_only': True},
        }
        depth = 1
```

From the extra_kwargs, the user is shown in the example in the swagger as shown in the image below.

[image]
Is there a way to hide that as it is not needed when making the request only on response? Not that it is affecting anything, I would just like not to have it there so that users do not feel the need to fill it out.

I tried reading the documentation and could not find any information. But maybe I missed it I am not sure.